# What's RFC 2396?

Tags: url, uri

Can anybody tell me meaning of term RFC 2396 it's related with the NSURL or something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) describes the syntax and format of a URI.

[Wikipedia has a good overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Refinement_of_specifications) over the sequence of RFC that defined and refined the URI spec.

The term RFC itself stands for Request for Comments, which sounds like it is a mere proposal, but most of them actually end up being the official industry standard.

> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments): An informational RFC can be nearly anything from April 1 jokes over proprietary protocols up to widely recognized essential RFCs like Domain Name System Structure and Delegation (RFC 1591).

Comment: In PHP, its stable and implemented under inbuilt filter_var function call, http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php, http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score -5):

RFC stands for request for proposal .... which sets standard for various networking phenomenon

Comment: request for comments, actually.

Comment: ... and it sets standards for lots of other things too ... and you've ignored the 2396 part of the question ...

Comment: i went by its natural meaning ... they are rather proposals

Comment: *What* 'natural meaning'? RFC stands for 'Request for Comment'. Period.