# NSURL returns nil in webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nsurl, nsurlrequest

Hello I’m using a `WebView` to load a specific URL from a String but in a `WebView` but it returns as nil.

```
var linkobject = "http://prf.hn/click/camref:1011l62a/creativeref:1100l4014/destination:http://nl.tommy.com/Tommy-Cares-Tas/C827884386,nl_NL,pd.html#!i=0&color=000&size=OS&utm_source=performancehorizon&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=FW15&utm_term=(UserID)&utm_content=feed&cmpid=ch:affiliate|dp:ecom|so:performancehorizon|cp:fw15|co:uk|pi:(UserID)|cr:feed&LGWCODE=8718937448230;88093;5350?LGWCODE=8718937448230;105153;6183"
if let url = NSURL(string:linkobject) {
    var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    if count(url.description) != 0 {
        self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        self.webView.loadRequest(req)
    }
}
```

This is my URL: http://prf.hn/click/camref:1011l62a/creativeref:1100l4014/destination:http://nl.tommy.com/Tommy-Cares-Tas/C827884386,nl_NL,pd.html#!i=0&color=000&size=OS&utm_source=performancehorizon&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=FW15&utm_term=(UserID)&utm_content=feed&cmpid=ch:affiliate|dp:ecom|so:performancehorizon|cp:fw15|co:uk|pi:(UserID)|cr:feed&LGWCODE=8718937448230;88093;5350?LGWCODE=8718937448230;105153;6183

Now i’ve read the in official documentation that this url doesn’t apply with the RFC 2396 standard, that's why it gives me a nil object.

*The NSURL class fails to create a new NSURL object if the path being passed is not well formed; the path must comply with RFC 2396*

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/

[What's RFC 2396?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426232/whats-rfc-2396)

Does somebody know a way how i could load this type of url in my webview or bypass or override NSURL in any way so my string can be converted to an NSURL? Love to hear suggestions, modifing the url is not a option because it’s supplied as an affiliate url.

Comment: which line that is returning the nil

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code what's that the url was taking a long time to load, so it kept crashing once the app loads.

Solution: Waiting until the url is finishing to load then put it back into the main queue

```
var stringUrl = "http://nl.tommy.com/Tommy-Cares-Tas/C827884386,nl_NL,pd.html?utm_source=performancehorizon&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=FW15&utm_term=(kledingnl)&utm_content=1100l4014&cmpid=ch:affiliate%7Cdp:ecom%7Cso:performancehorizon%7Ccp:fw15%7Cco:uk%7Cpi:(kledingnl)%7Ccr:1100l4014#!color%3D000%26size%3DOS"
    var url = NSURL(string: stringUrl)
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
      webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
```